# MS access iif statement

Tags: ms-access, report, iif

I'm building a report in MS Access and got stuck on something. Basically what I'm doing is making a report that will display a list of clients on particular days. At the bottom of the report i do a total for Client count with this statement...

```
=(Sum([numclientsM]) & " M ; " )
```

Below that I'm trying to take an average for all reported days but i keep getting a weird error saying "CANNOT HAVE AGGREGATE FUNCTION IN EXPRESSION (AVG(SUM([numclientsM]))).

Here's what I'm trying to do here... Check if sum(numclientsM) is <> 0 then, if it is then give me average:

```
=IIf(Sum([numclientsM]<>0),Avg(Sum([numclientsM])),"0.0")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check this at the moment, but try this:

```
=IIf(Sum([numclientsM])<>0,Avg([numclientsM]),"0.0")
```

Comment: Yeah i just figure it out myself -  that it wouldnt make sense to take an AVG of Sum(numClientsM) - since I'm looking for average client per day and i have all the client counts in detail.

Comment: Yes. Another way to explain it is that you were in effect trying to average a single number (produced by the sum).